# How to dump Symfony2 routes to nginx?

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have read that I should dump symfony2 routes into my web server to bypass the symfony2 router, for performance. I found an example for [apache](http://slides.seld.be/?file=2011-10-20+High+Performance+Websites+with+Symfony2.html#38).

How would you go about doing this for nginx?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, because of the way nginx is built, this is not possible. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2432

Comment: Moreover routes dumping will be removed in the next Symfony major version as the performance gain is minimal: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md